# many to many association with cancancan in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cancancan

My two controllers `user` and `web_cred`  are associated through `userPass` .
I applied `cancancan` gem but still unable to create a new web_cred ability class.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
    if user.admin?
      can :manage, :all
    else
       can :manage, WebCred, user_passes: {user_id: user.id}
      end
```

My controller

```
  load_and_authorize_resource :user
  load_and_authorize_resource :web_cred
  def create
    @web_cred = WebCred.new(web_cred_params) # Not the final implementation!
    if @web_cred.save
      userpass = UserPass.new
      userpass.user_id = current_user.id
      userpass.web_cred_id = @web_cred.id
      userpass.save
      redirect_to home_index_path
    else
      render new
    end
  end
```

Your answer will be appreciated.

Comment: At what statement did you have your error. `@web_cred.save` ?

Comment: which controller is this for? You won't be able to load and authorize resources for both user and webcred in the same controller like that

Comment: @Mr.Y actually  error was of  load _and authorize_resourses

Comment: i was doing it in wrong way which i solved 
thanks for your concern